# Bootstrap hide function not working on Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide the bootstrap modal dialog when click confirmation "Ok" button.
But this should be close before ajax call. I have check using  $('#step5CashModel').hide(); method but this worked only Mozilla Firefox not working chrome or IE.

Note : Without Ajax call, Hide function properly working on all browsers

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: `$(function () {
   $('#modal').modal('toggle');
});`

Comment: OK, the issue with your question is we have no idea how the example you have is fitting with your ajax call, and therefore we cannot advise you properly

Answer (score 0):

Close the modal using Javascript

```
$('#step5CashModel').modal('hide');
```